# Replacing elements in arbitrary nested lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have an arbitrary data set, given in the form of nested lists. I wish to replace all values in my data > 0 with 1, to create a sort of binary array. Similar to normalizing.

I'm imagining this is best done with a for loop. I tried using enumerate but got confused working with enumerate types.

For example:

```py
test = [[5,5,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,5]]

for i in range(len(test)):
    for j in range(len(test[i])):
        if j > 0:
            test[i][j] = 1
```

I'd expect:

```py
[[1,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1]]
```

but instead got:

```py
[[5, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need the values > 0 to be replaced, the condition should be as follows. Checking `j > 0` would mean all nested list values except the first one would be set to `1`.

```
test = [[5,5,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,5]]

for i in range(len(test)):
    for j in range(len(test[i])):
        if test[i][j] > 0:
            test[i][j] = 1
```